# Unable to resize a form using resize

Tags: html, css

i want one input to have the resize drag but does not work on my input. I tried on a button to see if it works and it does. (its a vue.JS page)

```html
  <div class="directioncolumn">
            <label for="description">Message*</label>
            <input class="message" id="message" type="text" required />
          </div>
```

```css
.message {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I thinks it's the textarea you want then

Comment: oh ok i see, it does work now. than you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="text">` is not meant to have more than one line.

If you want it to be resizable you'd have to use `<textarea>`:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Not resizable"></input><br>
<textarea>Resizable</textarea>
```